# Java regex matches to arraylist

Tags: java, regex

I have this code:

```
String line = "There were bear#67 with dog#1323 and cat#5475 in the forest";
String pattern = ".* ([^ ]+)#(\\d{4}).*";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
}  else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

It prints

```
Found value: There were bear#67 with dog#1323 and cat#5475 in the forest
Found value: cat
Found value: 5475
```

However I need to get all matches as `ArrayList`:

```
dog#1323, cat#5475
```

How would I do that?

Comment: What did you mean by *However I need to get all matches as ArrayList* ?

Comment: your regex should be `String pattern = "[^ ]+#\\d{4}";` and add `matcher.group(0)` to a list inside the loop

Comment: @YCF_L That resulting arraylist need to consist of two elements: String `dog#1323`, and String `cat#5475`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use a simpler regex without any capture group:

```
[^ ]+#\\d{4}
```

Which matches 1+ of a non-space characters before `#` and then 4 digits.

**Code:**

```
final String line = "There were bear#67 with dog#1323 and cat#5475 in the forest";

final Pattern r = Pattern.compile("[^ ]+#\\d{4}");    
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

while (m.find( )) {
   arr.add(m.group());
}

System.out.println(arr);
//=> [dog#1323, cat#5475]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all matches in a list, then you have to create one like this :

```
String pattern = "[^ ]+#\\d{4}"; // or "[a-z]+#\\d{4}" if you want only alphabets
//..
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    values.add(m.group(0));
}
```

---

Note: you need to use `while` loop and not an if statement(which match only one value).

---

Output

```
[dog#1323, cat#5475]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Stream` API, you can do it with a single statement.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s?)\\p{L}+#\\d{4}")
                                .matcher("There were bear#67 with dog#1323 and cat#5475 in the forest")
                                .results()
                                .map(MatchResult::group)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[dog#1323, cat#5475]
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `(?<=\s?)` specifies the [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for optional whitespace
2. `\p{L}+` specifies [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) [letter(s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
3. `#` specifies the char, `#`
4. `\d{4}` specifies 4 digits